# Connecting DC power check into circuit

Tags: power-connector

The schematic symbol for a typical DC power jack looks like this:

[image]

These things always have three terminals on the mechanical package. I believe the three terminals are called pin, shunt and sleeve. Although I am not sure what shunt really means here.

AC/DC power need two terminals. A third terminal could exist for safety purpose to earth the chassis. Now these power jacks have three terminals. How are these intended to be connected into a circuit since they always have three terminals?

Comment: There's a related answer I wrote not long ago: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/649940/2028

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps conflating the conductors of a DC barrel jack with the conductors on a TS or TRS plug.

With a DC barrel plug, there are two conductors, referred to as tip and sleeve (or sometimes center and shield, etc.). On a TRS plug, the conductors are referred to as tip, ring, and sleeve.

The symbol you have appears to be for a TS jack which connects the sleeve to the top pin, and the tip to the bottom pin, with a switched middle pin which can be used for various purposes such as turning on/off a circuit or detecting the presence of something plugged in.

Usually a barrel jack symbol looks more like this:

[image: DC barrel jack symbol]

The plug center pin corresponds to the jack pin 1 while the plug sleeve is jack pin 2, and jack pin 3 is switched.

When the plug is inserted into the jack, you can visualize the "triangle" contact on pin 2 moving away from pin 3 slightly, breaking that connection. This is frequently used in devices to disconnect the battery from the circuit when the unit is being powered from an external source.

In the case you aren't doing any switching, you can ignore pin 3. By "ignore" I mean you can leave it disconnected, or tie it to pin 2 (to which is it internally connected when no plug is present). Don't connect it to pin 1, which would create a short-circuit between pins 1 and 2 when nothing is plugged in.

While you can (and sometimes companies do) use a TS or TRS style plug instead of a DC barrel jack for power, I don't recommend that. TS/TRS/TRRS are typically used for connecting signals (usually audio) rather than power.

Comment: So you mean I can either leave 3 unconnected or connect it to either of the other two pins, preferrably the part (of the pin and sleave) which is grounded?

Comment: Correction: So you mean I can either leave *middle* unconnected or connect it to either of the other two pins, preferrably the part (of the pin and sleave) which is grounded?

Comment: @quantum231 You can leave the middle (3) pin unconnected or connect it to pin 2 (to which it already is internally connected when no plug is present). Don't connect it to pin 1 or you will create a short circuit between pins 1 and 3 when no jack is present.

Comment: Could you put the last comment into the answer please, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @quantum231 I've elaborated on what I mean by ignoring pin 3 as requested. :)

Comment: Note that in my comment I said "a short-circuit" between pins 1 and 3, but I meant 1 and 2.